# Reference on Fourier analysis on compact groups

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for a reference for Fourier analysis on compact (Lie) groups. The kind of theorems I would like the book to cover/do are the Peter-Weyl theorem, define Fourier transforms and use the Peter-Weyl theorem to derive the Plancherel theorem.The Peter-Weyl theorem(s?) can be found in multiple references but most of the books I look into do Fourier analyis on locally compact abelian groups.
Any suggestion is welcome, thanks! I am aware of Sepanski's text but I am looking for an alternate text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chapter 5 of Folland's *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis* should have what you need -- it is quite a short treatment, but it seems to be complete, provided that one is happy to fill in (routine) details in a narrative rather than go for the style of "Lemma 2.1.2, Lemma 2.1.3, Definition 2.1.4, Proposition 2.1.5, Lemma 2.2.1, etc".

I think there is also a readable treatment in Deitmar's *A First Course in Harmonic Analysis*, although the approach in that book is tailored to an audience without Lebesgue integration and hence might have some proofs which are non-geodesic work-arounds.

Answer (score 4):

For a reference which 1) has what you need, 2) is short and elementary (only undergrad point set topology needed, e.g., Ascoli/Arzela Theorem) yet includes detailed proofs, 3) is very clear and pedagogical, 4) is free; I think you will have a hard time finding better than the note ["Haar Measure"](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m421/haar.pdf) by Joel Feldman, on his UBC webpage.